# How to prove that for any two natural numbers a, b, there exist natural numbers c,d with a + d = b +c

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, proof-explanation, natural-numbers

I understand the intuition for how to do this, but I don't know how to formally prove it. For example, I know that if you take (a,b) to be (1,2), then a sample (c,d) could be (1,2) since 1 + 2 = 2 + 1. But how do I formally prove that such numbers c,d exist for an arbitrary c,d such that a,b,c,d are all in the naturals.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yes, sorry - that's what i meant!

Comment: Generalizing your example, what if you simply let $c=a$ and $d=b$?

Comment: The answer really depends on where you are in the formal construction of the natural numbers. If you know that the natural numbers are commutative, it suffices to reverse the two numbers. Otherwise, please state the set of axioms you're working from.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott . I fixed the title...........

Comment: @ΑΘΩ You're right, I used "The natural numbers" as shorthand for the obvious semigroup.

Comment: @jMdA Semigroup which is even a monoid, amongst others.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be careful with the statement that you are trying to prove.  As stated in the title of your question it is false because $c,d$ are chosen before $a,b$.  You need $c,d$ to be chosen after $a,b$, so it should be that for any two natural numbers $a,b$ there exists a pair $c,d$ such that $a+d=b+c$.  Having stated it correctly, a good way to prove it is an algorithm to find a $c,d$ pair.  One such (assuming you accept $0$ as a natural) is
If $a=b, c=d=0$
Else if $a \gt b, d=0, c=a-b$
Else $c=0, d=b-a$

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can always let $c=a$ and $d=b$. Then $a+d = c+d$.

If you mean a different pair of numbers.

Well, that isn't true.   $0 +0$ will have not $\{c,d\} \ne \{0\}$ so that $c + d = 0+ 0 =0$.

Nor is it true for $\{a,b\}=\{0,1\}$ and $a+b = 1$ will only have $\{c,d\} =\{0,1\}$ if $c+d =a+b= 1$.

However if we rule out that $\{a,b\} = \{0,1\}$

Then we can say let $\alpha = \min(a,b)$ and $\beta = \max (a,b)$.

Case 1:  $\alpha = 0$.  Then $\beta \ne 0, 1$ so $\beta \ge 2$.

Let $c = 1$ and $d = \beta -1$.

Case 2: $\alpha > 0$.  Then let $c = \alpha -1$ and $d = \beta + 1$.